# How to time a request to response lifetime?

Tags: servicestack

I'm currently adding a cookie to the request object, and subtracting it from the current time in the response, but I'm assuming there's a better way to do this. Also, re-using the same Cookie key probably won't do in real use case.

Any ideas?

```
            RequestFilters.Add((request, response, dto) =>
                               {
                                   request.Cookies.Add("Start", new Cookie("Start", DateTime.Now.ToString()));
                                   request.ResponseContentType = ContentType.Json;
                               });

        ResponseFilters.Add((request, response, dto) =>
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("{0} : [{1}]", request.RawUrl, DateTime.Now.Subtract(DateTime.Parse(request.Cookies["Start"].Value)).Milliseconds);
                                    request.Cookies.Clear();
                                });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, dont mess with the request cookies. One possible way is to just add the datetime to the request context in the request filter.

```
request.Items.Add("RequestTimer", DateTime.Now);
```

and then read it out in the response filter

```
DateTime.Now.Subtract((DateTime) request.Items["RequestTimer"]);
```

But the accurancy will depend on what order the request/response filters are run.

You might be able to utilize [ServiceStacks built-in profiling](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Built-in-profiling) instead