# ServiceStack: How to enable and view built-in profiler in self-hosted?

Tags: profiling, servicestack

When I read the docs on ServiceStacks built-in [profiling](http://docs.servicestack.net/built-in-profiling), I am not sure how to enable it in a self-hosted solution:

> Then starting it in your Global.asax, here’s how to enable it for local requests:

`Global.asax` doesn't exist for self-hosted, and I'm not sure where to enable it, or where to view the profiling results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MiniProfiler is dependent on ASP.NET's System.Web and only works in ASP.NET Framework.

You can register the [Request Logger](http://docs.servicestack.net/request-logger) plugin to capture request durations.

Comment: Ok, so the suggested way is... like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/18570820/178143

Comment: @Ted If you enable [Request Logging](http://docs.servicestack.net/request-logger) it already adds a Stopwatch to measure requests in "Request Duration" column although displays in XSD duration format, can show time format with:  /requestlogs?jsconfig=TimeSpanHandler:StandardFormat

Comment: Yes, I see that now, Thanks =)